# How to Show and hide table with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

Do you have any idea to rewrite the jQuery code to choose between to two selection options (Yes and No)? .

**I tried this in jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
    $("input:radio[name='decision']").change(function(){

    if(this.checked){
        if(this.value =='one'){
            $("#send_to_one").show() && $("#send_to_two").hide()
        }else if(this.value =='two'){
            $("#send_to_two").show()
        }else{
           $("#send_to_one").hide();
        }
    }
    });
});
```

**CSS :**

```
#send_to_one{
   display:none;
}

#send_to_two{
   display:none;
}
```

The "Yes" button `send_to_one` works well, if I select it, the correct informations are shown and the informations from `send_to_two` are hidden. If I select the "No" button the informations from `send_to_two` are shown, but the `send_to_one` informations are still shown. I tried to use the command from the first if statement, but this doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help, but always i add the recommended command the `send_to_two`action doesn't work.

This is my _form. Did i maybe make a mistake there?

> `<h2>Are you insured?</h2>
>         <div id="send_to">
>           <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="decision" value="one" checked="checked" />Yes<br/>
>           <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="decision" value="two" />No<br/>
>           <div id="send_to_one">
>             <div class="table-row-2">
>               <div align="center">
>                 <div class="field">
>                   <div class="table"><%= ........ %></div><div class="table"></div><div class="table"></div>
>                 </div>
>               </div>
>           </div>
>             <div id="send_to_two">
>               <div class="table-row-2">
>                 <div align="center">
>                   <div class="field">
>                     <div class="table">
>                     <div class="table"><%= ..... %></div><div class="table"></div><div class="table"></div></div>
>                 </div>
>               </div>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>`

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: I guess you only have to add the hide() command to the condition where value = two

Comment: I tried the add the line `$("#send_to_one").hide();', but this did´t work. Then the the "no" information was never shown.

Comment: Check your classes and names. Are they set correctly in your html? Perhaps add the html to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the hide statement in the second condition, your code should be :

```
if(this.value =='one')
{
    $("#send_to_one").show();
    $("#send_to_two").hide();
}else if(this.value =='two'){
    $("#send_to_two").show();
    $("#send_to_one").hide(); //<<---------- Adding this line to hide 'send_to_one'
}else{
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
}
```

Because you're using jquery better if you use jquery object `$(thhis)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
    $("input:radio[name='decision']").change(function()
    {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')  )
        {
            if($(this).val()==='one')
            {
                $("#send_to_one").show();
                $("#send_to_two").hide();
            }
            else if($(this).val()==='two')
            {
                $("#send_to_two").show();
                $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }
            else
            {
               $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#send_to_one").hide();

  $("input:radio[name='decision']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      if($(this).val()==='one')
      {
        $("#send_to_one").show();
        $("#send_to_two").hide();
      }
      else if($(this).val()==='two')
      {
        $("#send_to_two").show();
        $("#send_to_one").hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#send_to_one").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name='decision' value='one'/>Yes
<input type="radio" name='decision' value='two' checked/>No
<br/>
<div id="send_to_one">
  send_to_one div 
</div>

<div id="send_to_two">
  send_to_two div
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the add the line `$("#send_to_one").hide();', but always when i add this line, the "no" information is not  shown. I have the same problem with your code it works for the first statement, but not for the second. I tried to leave out the "else" statement, but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.checked){
        if(this.value =='one'){
            $("#send_to_one").show() && $("#send_to_two").hide()
        }else if(this.value =='two'){
            $("#send_to_two").show();
            $("#send_to_one").hide()
        }else{
           $("#send_to_one").hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this And check your code for missing `;`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send_to_one").hide();
        $("input:radio[name='decision']").change(function(){

        if(this.checked){
            if(this.value =='one'){
                $("#send_to_one").show(); 
                $("#send_to_two").hide();
            }else if(this.value =='two'){
                $("#send_to_two").show();
                $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
    $("#send_to_two").hide();
    $("input:radio[name='decision']").click(function(){
        if($(this).val() =='one'){
                $("#send_to_one").show();
                $("#send_to_two").hide();
        }else if($(this).val() =='two'){
                $("#send_to_one").hide();
                $("#send_to_two").show();
        }else{
                $("#send_to_one").hide();
                $("#send_to_two").hide();
        }
    });
});
```